# SQL Server ORDER BY - Sequencing ordering method

Tags: sql, methods, numbers, sql-order-by

I have these numbers in a column:

```
|numbers
|1
|1
|1
|1
|2
|2
|2
|3
```

I would like to order like this:

```
|numbers
|1
|2
|3
|1
|2
|1
|2
|1
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** in a subquery:

```
select number 
from (
  select number
    , rn = row_number() over (
             partition by number 
             order by (select 1)
           )
  from t
) as s
order by rn, number
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NNGS34159

results

```
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      1 |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Row count and partion query can do it .. Please go through it..